# Can one log in using multiple Google accounts with Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, login, google, authentication

I don't see an option anywhere though, perhaps some hack.

If not, can this be a feature request?

Comment: Why? I don't think you're really supposed to have multiple Google accounts in the first place. In what kind of scenario would this make sense?

Comment: Users could have two Google accounts, one from Google Apps, and one as individual account. Maybe the user want to log in with the Google Apps account from work, and with the individual account when at home. I cannot say how much users are in the same condition, though.

Comment: There may be the case where a user has two accounts and now wants to merge both accounts that both use google openid to log in.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's possible. Head over to your profile -> Settings -> [Your Logins](/users/mylogins/current) (under the "Access" section). Now select "Add login with Google", and proceed to log in to the preferred Google account. It will then be added to Stack Exchange as one of the available logins.

---

As Rebecca mentions in a [comment below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110831/can-one-login-using-multiple-google-accounts-with-stack-overflow/110839#comment-286966): If you're currently logged in to Google using a Google account that's already associated with your Stack Exchange account, make sure you log out of that Google account first!

Comment: Make sure that before you do this, you log out of any Google accounts, otherwise it'll skip prompting you for credentials and pick up the logged in account automatically.

Comment: Make sure to log out off chrome, too!

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss Care to clarify that statement? When logging in to _anything_ with Google, using a different account than the one I'm logged into Chrome with, I've never had to log out of Chrome. (And this is a near daily occurrence for me.)

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss you can't log out of Chrome. It's just a browser.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I assume, as someone constantly logged in to Chrome myself, they mean logging in to or out of a _profile_ on Chrome. Of course, this still shouldn't have any effect on logging in to Stack Exchange with a _different_ Google account.

Comment: @Kendra maybe [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2390059?hl=en-GB)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's actually exactly what I meant myself, and what I assumed they meant.

Comment: Just to say why I approved it... I thought that logging out of Chrome *could * help because being logged in might cause Chrome to think you are   logged in to your account....

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ well, back when this answer was posted I don't think Chrome had Profiles, so a new answer explaining it's possible to have multiple profiles, each with different SE account attached to it, might be better than changing this existing answer, which is about a single Chrome "instance" as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I can confirm that's not the case, so the rollback was justified, but that's a reasonable assumption to make. I can be completely logged out of the Google account that I'm logged in to Chrome with and not be considered by anything relevant to be logged in to Chrome.

Comment: In My Case, I use incognito. Then login using google account. go to profile > Add more login, don't click the google account again, but put the email account that we use for the google. It will automatically able to use the google sign in.